# Calculating a range (100:1000) of Fibonacci numbers using the repeat-loop in R

Tags: r, loops

When trying to find a code to calculate how many Fibonacci numbers are in the range between 100 and 1000, I tried using the repeat loop as seen below, but I am very unsure where to insert the specifications for the range (100:1000) and what I tried does certainly not work.

I know that the part with *head(x, -1) < 1000* is not correct - how could I fix the code?

```
 x <- c(0, 1)

 repeat {
  x <- c(x, sum(tail(x, 2))) 
   if(tail(x, 1) > 100) {
     x <- head(x, -1) < 1000
     break
   }
 }
 print(x)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you can try the code below, where you jump out of the loop when the newly generated item is not smaller than `1000`

```
x <- c(0, 1)
repeat {
  if ((v <- sum(tail(x, 2))) >= 1000) break
  x <- c(x, v)
}
x[x >= 100]
```

which gives

```
> x[x >= 100]
[1] 144 233 377 610 987
```